# Q: 9. spam varaible not defined for some reason

Tags: python, input

I'm using Python version 3.5.2 bit.

I have to write code that prints Hello if 1 is stored in spam, prints Howdy if 2 is stored in spam, and prints Greetings! if anything else is stored in spam.

My code doesn't recognize that I have defined spam and textbook answers don't give any information when running the program.

My code:

```
spam = input()

if spam == 1:
    print('Hello')
elif spam == 2:
    print('Howdy')
else:
    print('Greetings!')
```

Comment: It works for me on 2.7. How are you running your code?

Comment: Works for me on 3.5 (though it will always print Greetings because input() on 3.5 returns a string, and in python "1" != 1)

Comment: more generally: Gavin: you need to include the error message you're getting to have a Minimal/Complete/Verifiable question (or if the issue is just that you always get greetings, see my above comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input() on python 3 saves your input as a string, similar to how raw_input() works on python 2. You have to first convert your input to an integer before comparison using int() like this :

```
spam = int(input())

if spam == 1:
    print('Hello')
elif spam == 2:
    print('Howdy')
else:
    print('Greetings!')
```

or you can compare them as strings :

```
spam = input()

if spam == "1":
    print('Hello')
elif spam == "2":
    print('Howdy')
else:
    print('Greetings!')
```